# Отладка консольного приложения

Tags: delphi, консоль

Delphi 2009.

Какие опции нужно включить в проекте для пошагового запуска консольного приложения (APPTYPE CONSOLE) по кл."F9" в режиме отладки?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте точку останова в коде. По умолчанию вроде должна в режим отладки зайти. Или жмите F8.

Comment: К сожалению, это не работает.

Comment: @Алексей Кондаков, что конкретно не работает? Точки останова не ставятся?